# in Dax, how do I row match by some categorical column instead of getting a single value when using a numerical variable from another related table

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I use the values of a variable from a table B in a related table A in a such a way that it can be matched to each row of table A correspondingly?

I need to calculate a ratio as this

```
sum(A[event_number])/sum(B[client_number]
```

The 2 variables are from different related table. The relation between the tables are one (A) to many (B).
When I put this ratio on a matrix constructed with variables and measures from table A where the rows are stores, the denominator should be the client number per store but I only get the sum of all clients instead.

For example if a store "ASD" has 5 events it should get divided by 20 which are the clients related to that store and not 500 which is the sum of all clients for all stores.

I have tried using related when calculating the ratio, and allexcept to create a column of number of clients in A but nothing has given the expected result. Please help.

Comment: The relationship should propagate the filter. Please post your relationship diagram and what your data tables look like.

Comment: Hi @AlexisOlson actually I posted the full on question with the data model and some data examples 2 days back, my problem is more complex than what I have posted here but I haven't got no answers so I figure I could dechunk the question by bits and try to get a solution because the other post is so long I though maybe no one would care to read. I leave you the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61862593/power-bi-matrix-divide-column-a-by-corresponding-value-from-another-column-b-and if that is ok with you. Thank you for reading my question.